# need help on getuser profile details using mean stack

Tags: mean-stack

[[image: d]
Please help on the attached picture code as am unable to fetch the user details. once am ale to fetch the user details then please help me to edit also.

Answer (score 0):

In the back-end u need to send the user details also..in your code that won't happen.
So under the return part u need to add user json object.

```
res.status(200).json(user);
```